# How to read an aspx page content using ajax call?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, rest

I am developing a `Web Application` using `Javascript`, `JSP` and `RESTFul Web Services` which queries a `URL` without opening it in `Browser`. So I wanted to know how do I do it. I searched on web that I can have an `AJAX` call which will hit the `URL` and do the same but there is no clue from this which I can get. I just want to get the `innertext` of the `URL` which I am invoking. Also if possible through any other technologies any help on this much appreciated.